# Spring @PageableDefault default direction changes after passing sort

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Given I have this argument in my `@RestController` GET method:

```
@PageableDefault(size = 20, sort = "updated_at", direction = Direction.DESC)
```

When I GET without specifying `sort` then everything is fine: `sort == update_at` and `direction == DESC`.
But when I GET `...?page=1&size=33&sort=asdasd` it ignores default `direction` and sets it to `ASC`.

Did not get any results of this being a bug. Is it not ?

Comment: Did you try `sort=asdasd,desc`?

Comment: @AliDehghani - works, thanks. However I still think `direction = Direction.DESC` should not be ignored, but perhaps my point of view is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@PageableDefault() has defaut direction ASC value, you can add as following

```
   @SortDefault.SortDefaults({
           @SortDefault(sort = "name", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)
    })
```

So the request controller look like

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Brand>> findAll(
        @PageableDefault(sort = { "name", "displayOrder" }, value = 10)
         @SortDefault.SortDefaults({
         @SortDefault(sort = "name", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)                                                 }) 
          Pageable pageable) {
            Page<Brand> brandPage = brandService.findAll(pageable);

        }
```